# installing RC0 of kendo ui angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I've been testing the beta version, but since yesterday, the new RC came out, I've been trying to install it.

I have checked the version in the package.json, deleted it from there, and the directory in node_modules, and then reinstalled from npm again, 
but it looks like i'm on the same version, and the version number does not have RC in it.

how do I know I have the RC version and not an old one? is there a list somewhere with the version numbers in NPM?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an active Telerik account with either a license or a trial. Please check this page:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/

Comment: I know this, and did what it says, my question was how do I know that the version I have is the RC?
for example, i have     "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.13.1",

there is no way to know if 0.13.1 is the RC version or not wince there is no list that says which version is beta and which is RC?

Comment: the latest version of all components is the RC. Use npm view to list all the version available. For example `npm view @progress/kendo-angular-grid`